# yarn-env.sh : command not found

Tags: linux, hadoop

I have Hadoop 2.7.2 installed on Ubuntu 16.04. When I run the command:

> start-yarn.sh

It gives the following output:

> starting yarn daemons
>   /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/yarn-env.sh: line 122: rt: command not found
>   starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-brij-Compaq-15-Notebook-PC.out
>   /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/yarn-env.sh: line 122: rt: command not found
>   localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/yarn-env.sh: line 122: rt: command not found
>   localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-brij-Compaq-15-Notebook-PC.out
>   localhost: /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop/yarn-env.sh: line 122: rt: command not found

I am just curious about the last line that is

> yarn-env.sh
>   : command not found.

Should I be concerned? Or have I done anything wrong which resulted in this error?

Comment: `rt` is the command that isn't found

Comment: And why are you posting duplicates?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/791384/yarn-env-sh-command-not-found

Comment: @cricket_007 - Since I am not getting any answer on that site that's why I posted here

Comment: @cricket_007 -: why rt command not found? Is that an error?

Comment: There really isn't enough information to help. How did you install hadoop?

Comment: how to upload a txt file here? I have made my own document of it

Comment: You [edit] your question. Otherwise, pastebin.com would work for providing text content

Comment: Sorry, i have figured out my mistake. I had replaced export by rt by mistake. I have corrected it and now its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, i have figured out my mistake. I had replaced `export` by `rt` in

> bashrc

by mistake. I have corrected it and now its working